# how to run javascript when screen size over certain width size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, size, width

I want to run certain javascript only when the window width is over 1024.
The script is long. I've tried to combine them with

if ($(window).width() >= 1024

but it still not working.

Can someone help me?

This is the script I want to run when the width is over 1024 :

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(window).on("scroll resize", function() {
            var pos = $('#fixPlace').offset();
            $('.post').each(function() {
                if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top) {
                    var newDescr = $(this).find('.feature__description').html();
                    var oldDescr = $("#fixPlace").html();

                    $('#fixPlace').html(newDescr);
                    if (newDescr !== oldDescr) {
                        $("#fixPlace").css('opacity', 0.4).animate({ 'opacity': '1', }, 200);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).trigger('scroll'); 
        });
    });


    let fixPlace = '#fixPlace';
    let scrollStart = null;
    let scrollEnd = null;
    let floatBoxTop = 0.25 * $(window).height();


    $(document).ready(function() {
        scrollStart = $('#fixPlace').offset().top;
        scrollEnd = $('.transition').offset().top - 680;
    })


    $(window).scroll(scroll)

    function scroll() {
        let scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop() + floatBoxTop;
        scrollTop = Math.min(scrollEnd, Math.max(scrollTop, scrollStart))
        if (scrollTop === scrollStart || scrollEnd === scrollTop) {
            $(fixPlace).css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: scrollTop
            });
        } else {
            $(fixPlace).css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: floatBoxTop
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: which code you want to run under condition `if ($(window).width() >= 1024`? whole code or some part of it?

Comment: I want to run the whole code. Thank you so much.><